# jQuery scrollTop() returns zero for any element

Tags: jquery

On [my page](http://goo.gl/RKmMT7) I display with an `alert()` the `scrollTop()` value of the footer, which should be 2000 pixels or something but it finds zero. In fact it finds zero no matter for which element.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {            
        var footer = jQuery('footer').scrollTop();      
        alert(footer);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.scrollTop()` returns the scrollbar position, i.e. how many pixels that are hidden above scrollable area.

To get the position of an element, try this:

```
var footer = jQuery('footer').offset().top;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you expect the `scrollTop` method to return something different from what it actually does.

The `scrollTop` method returns how much the content of an element is scrolled down. As your footer doesn't have an `overflow` style that makes the content scrollable, you will never get anything other than zero from the `scrollTop` method.

I think that you are looking for the [`offset` method](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) or [`position` method](http://api.jquery.com/position/), which returns the position of the element relative to the document or the offset parent, respectively.